# How to use select for instant save with fullcalendar in yii2

Tags: yii2, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullcalendar (https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar) to save instantly on select an event whose data come from dropdown list before.

So, I need to take data from dropdown list, to save data on click and to display all data saved.

For this, I'm trying first to save an event on dayclick "normally" with a prompt for the title of the event.

But it doesn't work : the prompt come (alert too) but nothing is saved on my calendar.

I have already searched on the doc (fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) and on the demo (github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar-demo/blob/master/views/site/index.php) dut I don't find something that works.

I thing I don't understand something but I don't know what...

That's my view (index.php) :

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\helpers\Url;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    use yii\helpers\Json;
    use app\models\FeuilleDeJourResponsable;
    use yii\web\JsExpression;
?>
<div class="site-index">
    <?php
    $JSDayClick = <<<EOF
    function(start,end) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        var eventData;
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
            $('#w0').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
        }
        $('#w0').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
EOF;
?>
    <?= yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
        'id' => 'calendar',
        'clientOptions' => [
           // 'language' => 'fa',
            //'eventLimit' => TRUE,
            'selectable' => true,
            'selectHelper' => true,
            'droppable' => true,
            'editable' => true,
//          'theme'=>true,
            'fixedWeekCount' => false,
            'defaultDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'dayClick'=>new \yii\web\JsExpression($JSDayClick)
        ],
        'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/site/jsoncalendar']),              
    ]);
?>
    <?= Html::encode($JSDayClick); ?>  
</div>
```

And for my controller (SiteController.php) I try all I can find like this (www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2fullcalendar/) and this (github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar-demo/blob/master/controllers/SiteController.php)

Someone can help me ?

Thank you,
Sarah

EDIT :

I find something that works for my first step :

```
$JSDayClick = <<<EOF
    function(date) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        var eventData;
        alert(date.format());
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: date.format(),
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            alert(eventData.title);
            alert(eventData.start);
        }
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
EOF;
```

I just change "$('#calendar').fullCalendar" with the id "'id' => 'calendar',".

But for nextstep, I need to understand how to save the event on an other model I created (feuille de jour).

I'm keeping searching but I don't have any ideas...

Thank you again, 
Sarah

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: inside the variable JSDayClick you have to make another ajax call for saving data, create a new action in controller and then send data

Comment: Yafater, I have no errors.
Muhammad Shahzad, I will try what you said.
Thank you for answer me !

Answer (score 0):

It is not tested.

```
$JSDayClick = <<<EOF
      //dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) { 
        var titleNew = prompt('Event Title:'); var thedate1 = formatDate(date);

            $.ajax({
                url: Url::to(['/site/day-click-calendar-event']),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                      title: titleNew,
                      start: thedate1,
                      end: thedate1
                },
                success: function (data, response, event, date) {
                    //alert("success here");
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: titleNew,
                        start: thedate1,
                        end: thedate1
                    }, true);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oops! Something didn't work");
                }
            });
        },
```

In site controller:

```
public actionDayClickCalendarEvent()
{
 //save date
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. And I have an error but I don't understand so I can't correct it ...
This is my error "syntax error, unexpected 'actionDayClickCalendarEvent' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)"

With what I found here https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar-demo/blob/master/views/site/index.php I think it possible to not using ajax, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm trying to use it but it go to " alert("Oops! Something didn't work"); " I don't understand..